# pytorch conv2d value cannot be converted to type uint8_t without overflow

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm passing a `torch.Tensor` with a `dtype` of `torch.uint8` to an `nn.Conv2d` module and it is giving the error

> RuntimeError: value cannot be converted to type uint8_t without
>   overflow: -0.0344873

My conv2d is defined as `self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)`. The error comes in my `forward` method when I pass the tensor to the module like `self.conv1(x)`.  The tensor has shape (4, 3, 480, 640). I'm not sure how to fix this.  Here is the stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "cnn.py", line 54, in <module>

    outputs = net(inputs)

  File "/Users/my_repos/venv_projc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__

    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "cnn.py", line 24, in forward

    test = self.conv1(x)

  File "/Users/my_repos/venv_projc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__

    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/my_repos/venv_projc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 345, in forward

    return self.conv2d_forward(input, self.weight)

  File "/Users/my_repos/venv_projc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 342, in conv2d_forward

    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)

RuntimeError: value cannot be converted to type uint8_t without overflow: -0.0344873
```

Answer (score 13):

Converting the tensor to a float seemed to fix it `self.conv1(x.float())`