# RuntimeError: value cannot be converted to type uint8_t without overflow: -0.192746

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am new to Pytorch and am aiming to do an image classification task using a CNN based on the EMNIST dataset.

I read my data in as follows:

```
emnist = scipy.io.loadmat(DATA_DIR + '/emnist-letters.mat')
data = emnist ['dataset']
X_train = data ['train'][0, 0]['images'][0, 0]
X_train = X_train.reshape((-1,28,28), order='F')

y_train = data ['train'][0, 0]['labels'][0, 0]

X_test = data ['test'][0, 0]['images'][0, 0]
X_test = X_test.reshape((-1,28,28), order = 'F')

y_test = data ['test'][0, 0]['labels'][0, 0]

train_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_train), torch.from_numpy(y_train))
test_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_test), torch.from_numpy(y_test))

batch_size = 128
n_iters = 3000
num_epochs = n_iters / (len(train_dataset) / batch_size)
num_epochs = int(num_epochs)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, 
                                           batch_size=batch_size, 
                                           shuffle=True)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, 
                                          batch_size=batch_size, 
                                          shuffle=False)
```

Then, I found the following configurations (that I still have to adjust to fit to my data):

```
class CNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        
        # Convolution 1
        self.cnn1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        
        # Max pool 1
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
     
        # Convolution 2
        self.cnn2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        
        # Max pool 2
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        
        # Fully connected 1 (readout)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 4 * 4, 10) 
    
    def forward(self, x):
        # Convolution 1
        out = self.cnn1(x)
        out = self.relu1(out)
        
        # Max pool 1
        out = self.maxpool1(out)
        
        # Convolution 2 
        out = self.cnn2(out)
        out = self.relu2(out)
        
        # Max pool 2 
        out = self.maxpool2(out)
        
        # Resize
        # Original size: (100, 32, 7, 7)
        # out.size(0): 100
        # New out size: (100, 32*7*7)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)

        # Linear function (readout)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        
        return out


model = CNNModel()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

To train the model, I use the following code:

```
iter = 0
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        
        # Add a single channel dimension
        # From: [batch_size, height, width]
        # To: [batch_size, 1, height, width]
        images = images.unsqueeze(1)

        # Forward pass to get output/logits
        outputs = model(images)
        
        # Clear gradients w.r.t. parameters
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # Forward pass to get output/logits
        outputs = model(images)
        
        # Calculate Loss: softmax --> cross entropy loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        
        # Getting gradients w.r.t. parameters
        loss.backward()
        
        # Updating parameters
        optimizer.step()
        
        iter += 1
        
        if iter % 500 == 0:
            # Calculate Accuracy         
            correct = 0
            total = 0
            # Iterate through test dataset
            for images, labels in test_loader:
               
                images = images.unsqueeze(1)
                
                # Forward pass only to get logits/output
                outputs = model(images)
                
                # Get predictions from the maximum value
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                
                # Total number of labels
                total += labels.size(0)
                
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
            
            accuracy = 100 * correct / total
            
            # Print Loss
            print('Iteration: {}. Loss: {}. Accuracy: {}'.format(iter, loss.data[0], accuracy))
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-1fbdd53d1194> in <module>()
     12 
     13         # Forward pass to get output/logits
---> 14         outputs = model(images)
     15 
     16         # Clear gradients w.r.t. parameters

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight)
    348                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    349         return F.conv2d(input, weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 350                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    351 
    352     def forward(self, input):

RuntimeError: value cannot be converted to type uint8_t without overflow: -0.0510302
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60253449/pytorch-conv2d-value-cannot-be-converted-to-type-uint8-t-without-overflow) question already and think that the solution might work for me as well. However, I don't understand where in my code I can implement this.

What can I do to overcome this problem?

Ps.

I have used the following import statements:

```
    import scipy .io
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torchvision.transforms as transforms
    import torchvision.datasets as dsets
    from torch.autograd import Variable
    import cv2
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torch.optim as optim
    import torch.nn.functional as F
    import numpy as np
    import os
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageOps
    from torchvision import datasets, transforms
    from torch.autograd import Variable
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
    from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
    from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
    from torch.nn import Sequential
    from torch.nn import Conv2d
    from torch.nn import BatchNorm2d
    from torch.nn import MaxPool2d
    from torch.nn import ReLU
    from torch.nn import Linear
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed my problem was replacing `out = self.cnn1(x)` with `out = self.cnn1(x.float())`